# Using IF or Case with multiple in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, if-statement

I want to do something like this

this works
`Select ID, number, cost from table order by number`

number can be 2-xtimes but the cost and the same

```
1 A33  66.50

2 A34  73.50

3 A34  73.50
```

But I want to have

```
1 A33  66.50

2 A34  73.50

3 A34  0
```

I want to change it in the Sql to 0
I tried distinct or if then else.

I want to do something like this

```js
declare @oldcost int;

 Select ID, number, 
    if(cost=@oldcost) then
       cost=0;
    else
       cost=cost;
    end if
    @oldcost=cost;

from table order by number
```

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: What should be returned if there's another `4 A34  73.50` row, `0`? Or `4 A33  66.50`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and a `case` expression:

```
select ID, number,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by number order by id) = 1
             then cost else 0
        end) as cost
from table
order by number, id;
```

Note that SQL generally does not take ordering into account, so results can be returned in any order -- and even with an `order by`, rows with the same keys can  be in any order (and in different orders on different executions).

Hence, the `order by` includes `id` as well as `number` so you get the `cost` on the "first" row for each `number.`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it works !!!!!!!!! just added ...else 0 then its perfect !!!

Comment: @Lama, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. You can also choose to up-vote the answer by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.